# How to iterate key value pairs to FormData Append in React/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I have a lot of key value pairs that i need to append to FormData(). So i want it to iterate so i wont retype it again and again

**Object**

```
values: { username: 'johndoe', password: 123, contact_no: '18323223', place: 'LA' }
```

**Component code**

```
 onSubmit: (values) => {
      dispatch(signUp(values)).then((response) => {
        alert('Success');
      });
    },
```

**API Code**

```
export function signUpAPI(values) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(values).forEach((fieldName) => {
    console.log(fieldName, values);
    formData.append(fieldName, values);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be inches away from getting your code to work as you are already iterating over the key names, so you would need to do something, like:

```
export function signUpAPI(inputData) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(inputData).forEach(fieldName => {
    console.log(fieldName, inputData[fieldName]);
    formData.append(fieldName, inputData[fieldName]);
  })
  return formData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have key and value I like to use Object.entries:

```
export function signUpAPI(values) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values) {
    console.log(key, value);
    formData.append(key, value);
  });
}
```

Comment: There's a slight disadvantage of `Object.entries()` compared to `Object.keys()` in terms of performance, though.

Comment: Well you are correct, but when I work on forms I would rather use a more readable code always. If that Object indeed exceeds a couple of thousand key value pairs, I would choose performance...

Comment: When it comes to rendering UI, you would stick to most performant approaches, just as well, fighting for milliseconds.